# How do I define the following piecewise function?

Tags: function-construction

For 0<=t<=10, if 5t<=n<=5t+2, then f[n]=4n, and if 5t+3<=n<=5t+4, then f[n]=4n+1?

I would like then to use the specific values of f[n], for all n between 0 and 54 (t here is any integer between 0 and 10).

I tried:

```
f[n_] := Piecewise[{{4 t,     5 t     <= n <= 5 t + 2}, 
                    {4 t + 1, 5 t + 3 <= n <= 5 t + 4}}]
```

I tried f[5] (after Clear[t]). I got: f[5] is 4t if 5t<=5<=5t+2 and 4t+1 if 5t+3<=5<5t+4.

I would have liked to simply get 4.

Comment: Please post the code you tried, the output it gives you, and the output you would like to get instead.

Comment: So you have actually f[n,t] instead of f[n]?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I added the code... Thanks! I am new to this, Your help would be greatly appreciated. No, f is a function of n as I see it.

Comment: You say, "When I type f[5] I get 0", but this is actually not the case unless `t` was assigned a value.  Can you give a *complete* example, including all relevant definitions?  Do you have a definition for `t`?  This site gives good guidelines on how to ask a question: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this was what was intended:

```
c1 = {4 n, 5 # <= n <= 5 # + 2} & /@ Range[0, 10];
c2 = {4 n + 1, 5 # + 3 <= n <= 5 # + 4} & /@ Range[0, 10];
f[u_] := Piecewise[Join[c1, c2] /. n -> u]
DiscretePlot[f[x], {x, 0, 54}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! It works! (typo: it should be 4# instead of 4n - will edit this myself). Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

For 0<=t<=10, if 5t<=n<=5t+2, then f[n]=4t, and if 5t+3<=n<=5t+4, then f[n]=4t+1

```
f[n_,t_]:=(5t<=n<=5t+2)&&4t||(5t+3<=n<=5t+4)&&(4t+1)
```

I often use such defenition of condition-depending expressions, if I'm not going to differentiate or integrate them

Comment: Thanks! This is useful. The only thing is that I would really need a function f of n alone, without keeping track of the t.

Comment: I guess you can solve for t in terms of n and plug it in the function f[n,t], so I guess this will do it in this particular example. However, I am still curious on how would one define a function of n without solving for t. This will allow for a more complicated condition instead of 5t<=n<=5t+3...

Comment: f depends on two variables.

Comment: No, f as I wrote it, is a function of n alone. In order to define it, I used the auxiliary variable t. In other words, what I wrote means: f[n]=0 if 0<=n<2, f[n]=1 if 3<=n<=4, f[n]=4 if 5<=n<=7, f[n]=5 if 8<=n<=9, f[n]=8 if 10<=n<=12, etc

Comment: I wanted to have an efficient way of defining this function. Something that would work when the range is much larger or the conditional more complicated.

Comment: So the function of n I wanted is f[n,\floor{n/5}] (using the definition of f[n,t] given above).